# Grouped elements in a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, grouping

I have a matrix `A = [1 2 4 4 8 8 8 4 1 7 7 8 8 9]` and I want to create a new matrix which has number of same elements in A.

I have two 1, one 2, three 4, two 7, five 8 and one 9.

My new matrix should be [numbers;amount of each number]

```
newmatrix = [1 2 4 7 8 9; 2 1 3 2 5 1]
```

How can I create new matrix from A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Standard, recommended approach**: use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

   ```
   uA = unique(A);
   result = [uA; histc(A, uA)];
   ```
2. **Another possibility** is to do the counting with [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), and then use [`nonzeros`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html) to extract the values and [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the indices:

   ```
   s = sparse(1,A,1);
   result = [find(s); nonzeros(s).'];
   ```

   This second approach seems to be faster for small `A`, but the first is the recommended approach in general.

Comment: ... but about twice as slow for larger `A`'s if my benchmarking results are correct. Anyway, I like the approach =)

Comment: @RobertP. Yes, it's more of a curiosity than anything. I've edited the answer to state that the standard and recommended approach is the first

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by combining [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) like this:

```
newmatrix = [unique(A); histc(A, unique(A))]
```

The `unique` function returns a list of all the numbers in your vector, whereas `histc` counts each occurrence of the unique value in the original vector.

Note that for large vectors, [Luis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25362755/2338750) will be faster as it only calls `unique` once. However, if you're one of those who prefer one-liners, this answer should do the trick.

If your vector might be either vertical or horizontal, you the above will result in a `2nx1` vector instead of a `nx2` matrix. One possibility would be to call [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) like this:

```
result = reshape([uA; histc(A, uA)],[],2);
```